# Angular Directives on Primeng MenuItem

Tags: angular, primeng, menuitem

I am working with Angular and I would like to hide my menu based on permissions using the Angular custom directives

I created a `hasPermission` method like this:

```
hasPermission(permissions: string[]): boolean {
    const decodeToken = this.getDecodedToken()
    const permission = ConstantUtility.PERMISSION
    const userPermissions = decodeToken[permission]

    if (!userPermissions || !Array.isArray(userPermissions)) {
        return false 
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(permissions) || permissions.length === 0) {
        return false
    }

    const hasRequiredPermission = permissions.some((permission) => userPermissions.includes(permission))
    return hasRequiredPermission
}
```

And I call it in my custom directive

```
export class HasPermissionDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('appHasPermission') permissions: string[]

    constructor(
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private service: AuthService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('menu Item:', this.permissions)

        if (this.service.hasPermission(this.permissions)) {
            console.log('Has permission:', this.permissions)
            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
        } else {
            console.log('does not have permission:', this.permissions)
            this.viewContainerRef.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the menu html component

```
<ul class="layout-menu">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of model; let i = index">
<li
app-menuitem
[item]="item"
[index]="i"
[root]="true"></li>

</ng-container>
</ul>
```

and the Ts i would like to hide is here

```
model: any[]

constructor(
public appMain: AdminComponent,
) {}

ngOnInit() {

    this.model = [
      {
        label: 'Tableau de Bord',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
        routerLink: ['/admin/dashboard'],
        
      },
      {
        label: 'Fichiers',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Commune',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/commune'],
            
          },
          {
            label: 'Secteur',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/secteur'],
            
          },
          {
            label: 'Rue',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/rue'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Agence',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/agence'],
            permission: ['Permissions.Agences.Read']
          },
          {
            label: 'Cabine',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/cabine'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Panne',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/panne'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Devise',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/monaie'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Comptabilité',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Comptes',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
                routerLink: ['/admin/comptabilite/compte'],
              },
              {
                label: 'Journal',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
                routerLink: ['/admin/comptabilite/journal'],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: 'Type Client',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/type-client'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Type Transaction',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/type-transaction'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Police Abonnement',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/files/etat-pa'],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Saisie',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Dossier Client',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/client'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Tarification',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-dollar',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/tarification'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Taux de Change',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-folder',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/taux'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Parametres Facturation',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/fact-params'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Critere de Comptabilisation',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/critere'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Relevé',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/releve'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Statistique Panne',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/stat-panne'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Intervention',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
            routerLink: ['/admin/configuration/intervention'],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Traitements',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-database',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Génération Facture',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/generation-facture'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Paiements',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Ouverture Dossier',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
                routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/ouverture-dossier'],
              },
              {
                label: 'Paiement Facture',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
                routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/transaction'],
              },
              {
                label: 'Autres Paiements',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
                routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/autre-paiement'],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: 'Réclamation',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-megaphone',
            routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/reclamation'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Reduction',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
            routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/reduction'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Clôture de la Periode',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-lock',
            routerLink: ['/admin/traitements/cloture-periode'],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Editions',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-print',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Edition factures',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/generation-facture'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Listing des rélevés',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/listing-releve'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Fiche Abonné ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/fiche-abonne'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Journal de Vente ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/journal-vente'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Listing Recouvrement ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/listing-recouvrement'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Situation Journalière ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/situation-jour'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Situation Recette ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/situation-recette'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Reçu ',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            routerLink: ['/admin/editions/recu'],
          },
        ],
      },
    
      {
        label: 'Parametres Généraux',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-cog',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Parametre de la Societe',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-home',
            routerLink: ['/admin/parametres/societe'],
          },
          {
            label: 'Gestion Utilisateur',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Liste Utilisateurs',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
                routerLink: ['/admin/parametres/gestion-utilisateurs'],
              },
              {
                label: 'Gestion des roles',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
                routerLink: ['/admin/parametres/gestion-roles'],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: 'Affectations',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            routerLink: ['/admin/parametres/affectation'],
          },
          // {
          //   label: 'Societe',
          //   icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
          //   routerLink: ['/admin/parametres/societe'],
          // },
        ],
      },
    ]
}
```

Any idea on how I can implement this? Knowing that my permission comes like this:

```
['Permissions.Communes.Edit']
```